# Mergesort not working as intended with linked list

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list, mergesort

Preface:

I do not care about the viability of my particular merge sort algorithm. That is not what the question is about. I am curious as to why the program I have already written behaves the way it does, not about why I should use the STL or whatever. This is for learning purposes.

Question:

I have a linked list struct composed of `Node*`s. I've written up a semi-recursive merge sort algorithm (I say semi because the actual sorting is iterative technically) for this particular structure, and it doesn't quite work the way it should (sort ascending). When walking through the code with a debugger, it appears the actual sorting function `merge()` doesn't retain the newly sorted list throughout calls, and I cannot wrap my brain around how to do that. Could someone explain?

Here is a minimal reproducible example:

```
#include <iostream>
struct Link {
    Link(int d=int(), Link* n=nullptr) {
        data = d;
        next = n;
    }
    int         data;
    Link* next;
};

struct LinkList {
  Link* sentinel;
  size_t      size;

 LinkList(Link* h=new Link, size_t s=0) {
    size = s;
    sentinel = h;
  }

  ~LinkList() {
    Link* current = sentinel;
    while (current != 0) {
      Link* next = current->next;
      delete current;
      current = next;
    }
    sentinel = 0;
  }
};

// split into beg and end subLinkList using f/s ptr algorithm
void split(Link* sentinel, Link*& beg, Link*& end) {
    Link* s = sentinel, * f = sentinel->next;

    while (f != NULL) {
        f = f->next;
        if (f != NULL) {
            s = s->next;
            f = f->next;
        }
    }
    beg = sentinel;
    end = s->next;
    s->next = NULL;
}

// conquer (merge) elements from both subLinkLists into new sentinel
Link* merge(Link* beg, Link* end) {
    Link* sentinel = new Link;
    Link* tmp;
    for (tmp = sentinel; beg != NULL && end != NULL; tmp = tmp->next) {
        if (beg-> data < end->data) {
            tmp->next = beg;
            beg = beg->next;
        }
        else {
            tmp->next = end;
            end = end->next;
        }
    }
    if (beg == NULL)
        tmp->next = end;
    else
        tmp->next = beg;
    return tmp;
}

// recursive splitting and merging
Link* sort_merge(Link* sentinel) {
    Link* beg, * end;

    if (sentinel == NULL || sentinel->next == NULL)
        return sentinel;

    split(sentinel, beg, end);
    sort_merge(beg);
    sort_merge(end);

    return merge(beg, end);
}

// helper function calls sort_merge
void sort(LinkList &l) {
  sort_merge(l.sentinel);
}

void print(LinkList &l) {
  for (Link* n = l.sentinel; n != NULL; n = n->next) {
      std::cout << n->data << '\n';
    }
}

int main() {
  // set up linked LinkList 5->4->3->2->1->nullptr
  Link* sentinel = new Link(5 , new Link(4, new Link(3, new Link(2, new Link(1)))));
  LinkList l(sentinel,5);

  sort(l);
  print(l);

  return 0;
}
```

The output I want to have is

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

but it outputs

```
5
```

Comment: You're ignoring the return from `msort`.  Is that intentional?

Comment: Oh I am aren't I. I guess I'm not quite sure what to do with it, actually.

Comment: You implemented the functions and designed the API.  What is the return value supposed to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few issues:

1. `merge` returns the *last* node of merged list instead of the first. So change:

   ```
   return tmp;
   ```

   to:

   ```
   return head->next;
   ```
2. In `msort` the return value of the recursive call is ignored, but it is important, as it represents the first node *after* the sort operation. So change:

   ```
   msort(left);
   msort(right);
   ```

   to:

   ```
   left = msort(left);
   right = msort(right);
   ```
3. In `sort` the return value of `msort` is ignored so that the `head` reference of the list is never updated. So change:

   ```
   msort(l.head);
   ```

   to:

   ```
   l.head = msort(l.head);
   ```

Comment: That does it! Thank you so much for the incredibly clear and concise explanation. I wish there was someway I could repay you!